# What does mean "pot commited"?

Tags: meaning

I cann't understand the meaning of "pot commited" in this phrase:

**Law grads who lost their scholarships feel "pot committed," to use a poker term,**

Any idea?

Comment: This might help. Read the examples: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pot%20committed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the term "pot committed" requires an understanding of poker terms in general.

Here is [one definition](http://www.pokerstrategy.com/glossary/Pot-committed/):

> A player is pot committed or committed if he has already invested so
>   many chips in the pot that he can no longer fold if he is raised
>   all-in.

The linked site allows you to click on individual terms to know what they mean. For example:

> The pot is the prize pool consisting of all the bets made in a hand.

and:

> A player who folds lays down his cards and withdraws from the current
>   round of play. The bets he's already made stay in the pot and he
>   re-joins the game in the next round.

All-in means:

> to bet all the chips one has at the table. Once a player is all-in,
>   [...] he can no longer make any more wagers or call any more bets
>   [and] cannot be forced to fold.

So, as far as I understand it, pot committed means that somebody can, because of how much they have in the pot, be forced to bet everything they have remaining, and thereafter they have to play to the end, at a risk of losing everything.

If a law grad loses their scholarships, they can be forced into a difficult situation: they have invested a lot of time/money/effort such that they do not want to quit, yet they may not be able to afford to continue. They are stuck having to keep "playing", but with the risk of ending up with nothing.

Comment: I hope I didn't dumb it down too much. It was just in case you were as ignorant of poker as I am!

Answer (score 2):

I think the above is a poor explanation, specifically this part:

> > A player is pot committed or committed if he has already invested so many chips in the pot that he can no longer fold if he is raised all-in.

And this:

> So, as far as I understand it, pot committed means that somebody can, because of how much they have in the pot, be forced to bet everything they have remaining, and thereafter they have to play to the end, at a risk of losing everything.

The first part, the error is in "that he can no longer fold." In poker, you can fold at any point. In the second part, the error is in "be forced to bet everything."

What pot committed really means is: "You have so much invested, that the amount of additional investment to see it through is worth the risk and investment versus just quitting and losing everything so far." It is related to being "past the point of no return," where it's easier to just continue onto your destination than to turn around and go all the way back home. It also brings up, although stands somewhat opposed to, the "sunk cost fallacy," which basically says that people tend to keep investing (time, money, resources, etc.) into something because they see how much investment they've already put in, and what a shame it would be to quit; the sunk cost fallacy is that, in many cases, it would be wiser to quit when viewing the potential return on your investment, untainted by the past investment.

In poker terms (and I'll bring it back around to real life after a quick explanation), in many cases you can be pot committed without being in a position to lose all your chips. Generally, being pot committed means that the additional bets you'd have to make in order to stay in the game are relatively small compared to how much you've put in (there's also a factor of your total "stack" or amount you have to bet), that it's worth seeing through, in case the other person is bluffing, or you happen to hit one or more cards that makes you a winner. The "pot" part comes from the fact that, especially with multiple players, there is a multiple of the amount of money you've put in that can potentially be won. A few examples help:

Say you have $1,000. You have bet $100 to be part of a hand, and three other players have matched this bet. Now, the total pot (amount that the winner will win) is $400. To have the last card of the hand be dealt, it costs you $1 (and brings the pot to a total of $404). Even if you think you won't win, you are pot committed to seeing the card for $1; the amount of additional investment compared to your initial investment and the potential winnings is negligible. This is an extreme example, generally the ratio is not 100:1, but it serves as an obvious case that anyone can understand. Note that in terms of the errors made by the other poster, you aren't "forced" to bet $1 here, you can simply quit the hand, but of course, it would be wise not to.

Here is a better a example:

Say you have $1,000, and your opponents each have $2,000. You have bet $990 to get deep into a hand three other players. Now, the total pot is $3,960. At this point, you have essentially gone "all-in," i.e. bet all of your money, that saving that extra $10 is not wise, since again you could hit one or more cards to win the hand, the person could be bluffing, etc. In this case, your opponents have plenty of extra money, so they can easily bet $10 to force you to quit or go "all-in." Again, this is somewhat of an extreme example, generally a hand would not play out so obviously. It also somewhat depends on the bet size; for example, if you were playing in a game where the normal bets/antes were $0.10, then saving the $10 might be smart since it's such a huge amount of money relative to the normal betting size (but, you wouldn't get to sit down with, nor would you be able to accrue $1,000 in such a game, usually).

In neither of the above cases are you forced to do anything, but you are "pot committed," in that it would be wise to take a small risk to protect a larger investment. In real life poker, typically these numbers are much more balanced, and being able to understand an opponents sense of pot commitment/bet size management can provide leverage in a game. For example, if you know you will definitely win the hand, and the other player doesn't think they will, you can keep them giving you small sums of money or "bleeding" them by playing off their sense of being pot committed, whereas placing a larger bet would make them simply fold and cut their losses.

In your example, what it means for law school students is that, despite facing a sudden large cost of fees for tuition, etc., the time invested at the point that the scholarship is lost is worth protecting as an investment. The calculation here also includes what the fees and tuition are, how much time one has spent in school, whether one had to quit their job, other life circumstances, etc. Hope this helps.